# PHP: Constants & Bitwise separator as default argument to a method

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, class-constants

Im creating a class method and want to have a default argument value that contains constants:

```
<?php
class mq_series_client{
    function get($message_options = array('Options' => MQSERIES_MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQSERIES_MQGMO_WAIT, 'WaitInterval' => 500)){

    }
}
```

However I'm getting a Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|'

I could do this:

```
<?php
class mq_series_client{
    function get(Array $message_options = null){
        if(!isset($message_options)){
           $message_options = array('Options' => MQSERIES_MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQSERIES_MQGMO_WAIT, 'WaitInterval' => 500);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem very clean. I wish the first way would work!

Is there a better "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the first option is not valid, as according to [this page](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> The default value must be a constant
>   expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function
>   call.

Experimenting a bit, it looks like expressions are not accepted, like:

```
<?php
    function get($options = array('test' => 1+1)) {

    }
}
?>
```

which chokes on the `+` -- presumably because it is not a “constant expression.“

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, that better explains why my first attempt failed. Quite frustrating actually, it would be much cleaner if it worked that way.